# Remove a ckeditor dialog registration

Tags: ckeditor

How do I prevent a builtin dialog from showing up? For example, let's say I want to prevent the link dialog from showing up to limit what my users can do with links.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm I think I found the answer to my question: just replace the existing with a new registration:

```
editor.addCommand('link', {
        exec: function (editor) {
            alert('Boo!');
        }
    });
```

Let me know if there's a better way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

> For example, let's say I want to prevent the link dialog from showing up to limit what my users can do with links.

```
CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function( config ) { config.removeDialogTabs = 'link:target;link:upload;link:advanced'; };
```

See also [removeDialogTabs](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.config-cfg-removeDialogTabs).

Comment: Can this be used to remove the dialog entirely? Meaning if I remove all its tabs, will there be an empty dialog pop up?